# This quick note is to

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which one would you consider correct:

This quick note is to just inform you that...

Or

This is a quick note to just inform you that...

Obviously, the second one is widely used, but I don't know about the first one

Comment: Although the first sentence is a little unusual, they are both grammatical. The specific way in which you form the sentence is subjective and open to personal opinion and style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

> This is a quick note to inform you [...]

If you would like to maintain the "just", it should go in before the subject:

> This is just a quick note [...]

Without the "just" your first sentence would be valid. It focuses on the purpose of the note, whereas the second focuses on the existence of the note: "A note to inform." vs. "This is a note."

Comment: Using just between is and to as "This quick note is just to inform you" would still be wrong?

Comment: No, that would be correct, though I'm not sure why...
Perhaps it needs to come directly after the verb?